# Where can I get feedback on my martial arts workout video?

Tags: discussion

I was wondering where is the best place to post a video of my MA workout and get some feedback on it? I've got it on youtube, but just need to find some audience with constructive feedback.

I didn't want to post it here as it seems too selfish, but I'm hoping there is another stackexchnage for this? Where could I do this?

Comment: I was going to downvote this and close it, but actually it is *a really good question*.  Posting a series of questions on specific aspects of your video would work here but I am not sure a "cover it all" would. If not, have you tried MA forums?

Comment: I'm voting to move this to Meta because this seems more like a discussion thing.

Comment: Thanks guys, yes I posted it in fightingarts , but that place has tumbleweeds rolling through it these days. There are places like hudl but those are for professional athletes. I was just looking for a forum-like feedback machine by some knowledgeable eyes.

Comment: Can't we revive our chat room for this? I think it would be a suitable place to discuss things like this, but it seems chat is frozen due to long term inactivity.

Comment: I just unfroze the [chat]. Go ahead and discuss!

Comment: Thanks Matt! I have now posted a discussion in #30664364 thread of The Dojo room.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to reopening the [Martial Arts Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) , my feedback request is posted in The Dojo [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30664364#30664364)